# unable to append pandas Dataframe to existing excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I am quite new to Python/Pandas. I have a situation where I have to update an existing sheet with new data every week. this 'new' data is basically a processed data from raw csv files which are generated every week and I have already written a python code to generate this 'new' data which is basically a pandas Dataframe in my code. Now I want to append this Dataframe object to an existing sheet in my excel workbook. I am already using the below code to write the DF to the XL Workbook into a specific sheet.

```py
workbook_master=openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\Claro\Pre-Sales\E2E Optimization\Transport\Transport Network Dashboard.xlsx')

writer=pandas.ExcelWriter('C:\Claro\Pre-Sales\E2E Optimization\Transport\Transport Network Dashboard.xlsx',engine='openpyxl',mode='a')

df_latency.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Latency',startrow=workbook_master['Latency'].max_row,startcol=0,header=False,index=False)

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

now the problem is when i run the code and open the excel file, instead of writing the dataframe to existing sheet 'Latency', the code creates a new sheet 'Latency1' and writes the Dataframe to it. the contents and the positioning of the Dataframe is correct but I do not understand why the code is creating a new sheet 'Latency1' instead of writing the Dataframe into existing sheet 'Latency'

will greatly appreciate any help here.

Thanks
Faheem

Answer (score 1):

By default, when `ExcelWriter` is instantiated, it assumes a new Empty Workbook with no Worksheets.

So when you try to write data into 'Latency', it *creates* a new blank Worksheet instead. In addition, the `openpxyl` library performs a check before writing to "avoid duplicate names" (see [openpxyl docs : line 18](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/default/openpyxl/workbook/child.py)), which numerically increment the sheet name to write to 'Latency1' instead.

To go around this problem, copy the existing Worksheets into the `ExcelWriter.sheets` attribute, after `writer` is created.
Like this:

```
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in workbook_master.worksheets)
```

Comment: Thanks alot Gary. This solved the issue. But i dont understand why ExcelWriter doesnt instantiate book and worksheets when the object is created and specially when the mode='a' plus it also doesnt mention anywhere on the ExcelWriter documentation about this issue. So unless you analyze ExcelWriter code and crack it, you wouldnt have been able to figure it out. Anyways thanks a zillion for this. Really solved my problem!!

Comment: Yes, I agree that it is confusing. Perhaps we should create an issue on github for pandas for this use case so as to improve usability.